# Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute is not defined

Tags: vb.net, excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

Using a script I found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3475/execute-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-from-integration-services-package/) Problem is it's for 2012 and I'm using 2008.

I've handled all of the personal stuff(connections, variables, URLS, etc.) But I keep getting an error when I try to run the script.

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute is not defined

Using VB.

```
    Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Diagnostics
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum
    Protected Sub SaveFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal localpath As String)
        Dim loRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim loResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
        Dim loResponseStream As System.IO.Stream
        Dim loFileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(localpath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
        Dim laBytes(256) As Byte
        Dim liCount As Integer = 1
        Try
            loRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
            loRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            loRequest.Timeout = 600000
            loRequest.Method = "GET"
            loResponse = CType(loRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            loResponseStream = loResponse.GetResponseStream
            Do While liCount > 0
                liCount = loResponseStream.Read(laBytes, 0, 256)
                loFileStream.Write(laBytes, 0, liCount)
            Loop
            loFileStream.Flush()
            loFileStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim url, destination As String
        destination = Dts.Variables("Folder_Destination").Value.ToString + "\" + "Report_" + Dts.Variables("ReportParameter").Value.ToString + "_" + Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd") + ".xls"
        url = "http://localhost:8080/ReportServer?/MyReports/SSIS_Execute_SSRS_Report&rs:Command=Render&Productkey=" + Dts.Variables("ReportParameter").Value.ToString + "&rs:Format=EXCEL"
        SaveFile(url, destination)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I haven't gotten down adding code in SO yet. But I think everyone will get the idea from the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

The Addin.Addins have been deprecated.

```
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
```

is fine for 2010 but for 2008

```
<System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version:="1.0", Publisher:="", Description:="")> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
```

is needed.

Hope that helps anyone else out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message trying to import an existing SSIS 2016 package into a new solution.

I found that when I created my new solution in VS/TFS it set the target server version to 2017.

I changed the TargetServerVersion back to 2016 and it now works.

In VS, Right click on Project > view Properties.
Look under Configuration properties > General > TargetServerVersion.